# What does "turn left right ahead" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'd like to know what the sentence means:

> So, for you to go take the formularies,  you need to *turn left right ahead* , get beside that line and take one of those and give it to mr. Jeffrey

So, does that mean you have to *turn left right now* or you need to *turn left and go straight on*?

Comment: "Right ahead" is an idiom meaning "a short distance ahead".

Comment: hahahaha English.... turn left right ahead.... oh my, a native speaker from S Africa would always say that and, well, drove me crazy. I still am.He would also go. drive directly, directly, by which he meant straight, dont turn (I was thinking directly to what?)

Comment: All-too-common dialogue: **Driver**:  "Turn left here?" **Passenger**: "Right!" **Driver**: "Turn right?" **Passenger**: "No, left! Left! Aaah, you missed it."

Comment: lol! Life gets interesting and busier if we dissect every thing we see, hear and feel. If I were to hear this, I will assume the speaker means make a left turn right ahead.

Comment: Unfortunately, the word "right" has more than one meaning.  So does "left".

Answer (score -1):

Turn left right now. (Turn left soon.)

Comment: But right now and soon are two different things.

Comment: Please include an explanation for your choice.